# Se puede añadir evento click con jquery a una determinada celda de una fila de una tabla que se crea con foreach?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, json

Estoy tratando que añadir el evento click() y desencadenarlo cada ves que presiono click sobre un input, pero no consigo hacer oido al evento, no obtengo resultado - "Las filas se crean en un for y deseo añadir el evento a cada una de ellas".

CAPTURA DE MODAL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CÓDIGO JQUERY- AJAX DONDE SE INSERTAR LAS FILAS:

```
if(json.result.representantes_legales.length>0){
                    $('#box_tabla_rep').show();
                    $(json.result.representantes_legales).each(function (i, v) { // indice, valor
                        var row = '<tr>  <td>' + (i+1) + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + v.tipodoc + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + v.numdoc + '</td> ' +
                            '<td>' + v.nombre + '</td> ' +
                            '<td>' + v.cargo + '</td> ' +
                           /* '<td>' + "firma" + '</td> ' +*/
                            '<td> <input type="file" class="btn-primary input-firma" title="Seleccione archivo"></td> ' +
                            '</tr>'; //esto seria lo que contendria la fila

                        $('#table-repre tbody').append(row);
                    });
                }
```

CÓDIGO DE EVENTO CLICK AL HACER CLICK EN EL INPUT FILE:

```
 $('.input-firma').click(function () {
    alert('hiciste click en el input');
});
```

Comment: Agrégale un id al td que quieras manejar y la función sería similar a la del .input_firma

Comment: ya lo intente y no desencadena el evento

Comment: Intenta con `$('#table-repre tbody').on('click', '.input-firma', function() {`

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar el evento onclick `onclick="recargarPersonal()"` Yo lo utilizo en un boton,  eso manda llamar a la función que estas indicando, ya sea que este en un archivo js o en el script del head, o al final de tu archivo donde la ocupas,  esta es la función que carga este onclick:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#recargarPersonal").click(function(e){
         $("#Unidades").on('change', function(){ 
            $("#Unidades option:selected").each(function(){ // escucha el cambio de un select
                var cadenaCCT = $('#Unidades').val();
                alert("cadenaCCT"+cadenaCCT);  // muestra el valor seleccionado
             //aqui tenia instrucciones Ajax las quite...   
    });
   
});
```

Espero te sirva como referencia